# Swig template engine and Sails.js - how to change tagControls

Tags: node.js, sails.js, swig-template

I want to change default [Swig tagControls](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/api/#SwigOpts) {% ... %} to {? ... ?} I am using sails.js framework.

I add to config folder swig.js file, which contains:

```
module.exports.swig = {

  SwigOpts: {
    'tagControls':  ['{?', '?}']
  }

};
```

But it doesn't work, view in the browser look like this:

```
{? for user in users ?}
{? user.email ?}
{? endfor ?}
```

So, tags wasn't interpreted. Is my config file wrong? Standard tags {% ... &} works fine.

Comment: Did you restart your server after altering the config?

Comment: Yes of course, a few times.

Comment: No offense - just making sure the obvious was covered. Based on the docs, looks like it should work... (i know that's not entirely helpful).

Comment: So, it might be Swig issue?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the implementation in Sails.js.  But again - it's just a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work: in your `config/views.js`

```
engine: {
  ext: 'swig', // Or `html`, whatever you are using
  fn: function (pathName, locals, cb) {
    var swig = require('swig');
    swig.setDefaults({tagControls: ['{?', '?}']});
    return swig.renderFile(pathName, locals, cb);
  }
},
```

As for the `config/swig.js` and `module.exports.swig`, I don't think it's being processed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if someone need to change the scape var like me (is better to work with swig and angular) just need change or add `varControls` to the config object

```
engine: {
  ext: 'swig',
  fn: function (pathName, locals, cb) {
    var swig = require('swig');
    swig.setDefaults({varControls: ['[[', ']]']});
    return swig.renderFile(pathName, locals, cb);
  }
}
```

Comment: this many not be an answer to the question, but I found this useful since I use Angular and Swig on my Sails App (and didn't want to keep typing verbatim/raw tags everywhere)